# Styling makes javascript code not function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I was playing around with this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/VmVAq/

As you can see, on page load, only DIV 1 is displayed. And as you can notice, the styling is inline so I decided to add it to the header:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/2/

This is where the problem is. Now on page load, all the DIVs are displayed, **why?** How did I break the code?

In case you want to review the code here:

Original:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

             <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
                <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>


             <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
                <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>

             <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
                <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Styled:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}
</script>

<style>
    #scoopout {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

             <div id="scoopout">
                <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1">Div #1</div>


             <div id="scoopout">
                <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">Div #2</div>

             <div id="scoopout">
                <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3">Div #3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://robzu.com/sscce-short-self-contained-correct-compilable-example). Please post your applicable code directly, instead of just a link.

Comment: try pasting the code where it belongs, there's a separate field for js code

Comment: This is what @EliasVanOotegem means: [jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/4/).

Comment: @PPvG That example you posted breaks the whole thing, clicking on the show div boxes does not have any effect...?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Yes, sorry, I didn't test it. It wasn't really meant as a solution. Try this: [jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/7/) (with the JS set to "no wrap" instead of "onload" -- see the left bar).

Comment: Thanks for posting that PPvG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've rewritten your fiddle, and even though you've accepted an answer, it might prove helpful in the future.

First thing you need to know is that functions in JS are objects, so you can set properties. Doing this enables you to track which element is visible at any given time, without the need for evil globals, or unbinding and rebinding your events and using closures. I'm guessing you have heard of them, but there somewhat unfamiliar territory, judging by your code.

The next thing I did was identify all the clickable elements, hide the *"secret"* divs, and attach a click event to your links (using the `reveal` class). Then, I assign a reference to the element that has been made visible, so you can hide it again on a next click event.

Since you're using jquery 1.4.4 (time for an *upgrade* I'd say), I kept it quite simple:

[a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/9/)

The code here, for remarks/questions: comments are welcome

```
$(document).ready(function()
{//All this code will be executed when the page has loaded
    $('.newboxes').each(function()
    {
       $(this).hide(); 
    });
    $('.reveal').click(function showOne()
    {
       if (showOne.visible && showOne.visible.hide)
       {
           showOne.visible.hide(600);
       }
       if (showOne.visible && showOne.visible.attr('id').replace('newboxes','myHeader') === $(tihs).attr('id'))
       {
           showOne.visible = undefined;//set to undefined, otherwise the next click will try to hide the hidden div
           return;//stop here, don't invoke show method
       }
       showOne.visible = $('#'+$(this).attr('id').replace('myHeader','newboxes'));
       showOne.visible.show(200);
    });
    $('#myHeader1').click();//show the first div on page load
});//anything after this will be run as soon as possible, likely before the page loads
```

Comment: I've added a little extra check [and updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/9/) so now clicking the same link a second time just hides the div again. A lot cleaner than hiding and showing it again IMO :)

Comment: I tried to add **$(function() { showOne('newboxes1'); });** to make DIV 1 appear on page load but it did not work, do you know why?

Comment: because the `$(function() { showOne('newboxes1'); });` is another event handler: it means if the page loads, execute the `showOne` function and pass a string as parameter. But the function doesn't work that way anymore. If you want to show a single div on load, just use my code and before the last `});` type `$('#myHeader1').click();`, I'll add that to my answer, too

Comment: I see, yes please update your answer, also, your solution to hide the DIV when clicking on it again does not function properly. It reopens it instantly afterwards ;)

Comment: I've already updated my answer: I just added the second to last line, and it works like a charm. Also, `and updated the fiddle` is a link to a new _version_ (url has 9 at the end), that's the one where the div's don't reopen. Anyhow: the code I posted here is the full monty: div's don't get reopened with this code, and the first div is shown on page load

Comment: Glad to help, but since it seems that my answer was the one actually solving your issue, without fugly in-html js, it would be nice to see it marked as accepted answer, too

Answer (score 5):

In the first fiddle, you give some of the elements `display: none`.  You don't do that in the second example.

In other words, you did more than just move the style rules to a `<style>` element — you also got rid of some of the CSS.

You could add a "ready" handler that shows just one.

```
$(function() { showonlyone('newboxes1'); });
```

Comment: Also, you can't have multiple elements with the same id, as you did `<div id="scoopout">`. Change that to `<div class="scoopout">`, and your CSS selector from `#scoopout` to `.scoopout`.

Comment: That did not work, changed it to class and adjusted my CSS selector but all DIVs are still visible upon page load, check yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym96t/5/

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You can use a `ready` handler as Pointy suggests, since you removed the code that was hiding all divs but one.

Comment: @Pointy can you kindly provide me a working example of the "ready" handler that you are suggesting? I added it in a script tag but do not know what to do after that, a fiddler would be useful.

Comment: The code I posted is a ready handler; I'll update your fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I do not understand how to implement the code you suggested. I just added it in a script tag in my header, but do not know what to do afterwards. This is why I request if you could be kind and update a fiddler and I can have a look.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Note that the code Pointy posted is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){ showonlyone('newboxes1'); });` (however it doesn't mention `ready` explicitly).

Comment: @Pointy I usually don't edit other people's code, so excuse me on this one (removed camelCase on fn call).

Comment: @bfavaretto Is there any difference in which one I should use in this scenario?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Oh I see, the reason of why this solution didn't work originally was because you posted "showonlyone" as "showOnlyone" and I just copy and pasted it without looking further. All is good now though.